# Sorting an array of strings and numbers while maintaining the array's original order

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I just took a coding interview (ugh.) and I could not for the life of me figure this out.

**Question**:

**Double Sort**
Please write a javascript method which accepts an array of strings. Each element can either be a number ("165") or a word ("dog"). Your method should sort and return the array such that (1) The words are in alphabetical order and the numbers in numerical order, and (2) the order of words and numbers within the array is the same.

Examples (input => output):

sort(['5', '4', 'dog', '1', 'cat'])

=> ['1', '4', 'cat', '5', 'dog']

sort(['dog', 'cat'])

=> ['cat', 'dog']

sort('5', '3')

=> ['3', '5']

I was able to write a basic sort function that sorted the array alphabetically and numerically, but I was unable to maintain the array's original order. This was what I managed to come up with in the time limit:

```
var multiSortArray = [5, 4, 'dog', 1, 'cat'];

var multiSort = function(arr) {
    var sortedArray = arr.sort();
    console.log(sortedArray);
}
multiSort(multiSortArray); 
which outputs: [1, 4, 5, "cat", "dog"]
```

Any help'd be appreciated, I'm irritated as hell I couldn't figure this out. All I could find in SO was ordering **objects** which I'm not sure is what I need to do (or maybe I do. I have no idea.)

Thanks everyone!

Comment: *"... the order of words and numbers within the array is the same..."* What does that mean? `[5, "cat", 3, "dog"]` should return `[3, 5, "cat", "dog"]` but `["cat", 5, 3, "dog"]` should return `["cat", "dog", 3, 5]`?

Comment: I believe that it should sort the strings and numbers but keep them in their original places. so  
[3, 5, 'cat', 2, 'ant'] --> [2, 3, 'ant', 4, 'cat']. so indexes that are numbers remain indexes, same with strings, but otherwise they're sorted alphabetically/numerically.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I believe that the array should be sorted, however an array position that was originally a string should remain a string, and an array position that originally held an integer should remain an integer.

Comment: I think the correct output would be - [1, 4, 'cat', 5, 'dog']

Comment: @zenwraight OP said that in his question, it's his first example. He's saying that his own output is wrong.

Comment: @zenwraight yes, exactly! I got it to sort everything but it moves it reorders the array in the bargain.

Comment: That's quite an interesting task. Maybe first split the array into an array of numbers and an array of strings, while remembering the indexes for strings. Then sorting numbers and strings independently. In the end combine sorted string and number arrays using the original string position indexes.

Comment: I agree with @Danmoreng. Pull out the numbers and put them in an array, pull out the strings and put them in a different array, sort them independently. Then replace values in the original array by iterating through them - "If `this` value is a string, replace it with the next value from the string array. If `this` is a number, replace it with the next value from the number array." Something along those lines.

Comment: And they really gave you the numbers as strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it:

```js
var arr = ['5', '4', 'dog', '1', 'cat'];

// STEP 1: split the original array into two arrays, one for strings and one for numbers
var str = [], num = [];
arr.forEach(e => isNaN(e)? str.push(e): num.push(e));

// STEP 2: sort the two arrays
str.sort();
num.sort((a, b) => a - b); // because the numbers are actually strings we need to do a - b to implicitly convert them into numbers and sort them using the substraction result

// STEP 3: for each element in the original array, if the original item was a string then replace it with the first item in the string array (and remove the added item), if the original item was a number, do the same with the num array
arr.forEach((e, i) => arr[i] = isNaN(e)? str.shift(): num.shift());

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: while all of them are right, this is the one that I understand well enough to talk about. I appreciate you all taking the time to help a lady out :)

Answer (score 7):

Just split the numbers and words into seperate arrays, sort them, and add back together again

```js
function sort(arr) {
  let n = arr.filter(x =>  isNaN(x)).sort((a,b) => a.localeCompare(b));
  let c = arr.filter(y => !isNaN(y)).sort((a,b) => a-b);

  return arr.map(z => (isNaN(z) ? n : c).shift());
}

console.log(sort(['5', '4', 'dog', '1', 'cat']));
```

Comment: What if a string is `""`? ;-)

Comment: `["14", "111"]`.

Comment: neat af ...few questions, I'm beginner-to mid level so while I get the gist some of the finer points of the process are going right over my head

1 isNan -I haven't seen this before, is this a part of e6? testing, basically, if the value of (x) is NaN or not? I don't see it declared anywhere so I guess it has to be.

2 still not up on my e6, is => like declaring an anonymous function within filter() ?

3 what is z in this context?

thanks so much for going through this with me. I want to make sure I really understand it in the off chance the hiring manager wants to discuss it

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir - good point, should probably sort numerical strings as actual numbers, edited.

Comment: @adeneo: The edit breaks it, you can't directly return the result of `>` in a `sort` callback. You wanted `a - b`. In my version, I also used `localeCompare` for strings for a more accurate collation (on browsers that support ECMA-404).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - worked for me, but I have no idea why I didn't just subtract instead? Thanks.

Comment: @adeneo: It working was a happy coincidence. :-) It's surprising how often it does, actually.

Comment: @12Noone - `isNaN` has been around a while, like since ES1 or something. It just checks if the value is numeric or not, so it can be used to easily split the numeric strings from the non-numeric strings.

Comment: And `z` is just the argument, as in `arr.map( function(z) { ...` etc.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that would have come to my mind would have been to make a map of which type of thing was in which index, then separate and sort, then zip them together again according to the type:

```
function sort(a) {
    const type = a.map(e => /^\d+$/.test(e));
    const nums = a.filter((e, i) => type[i]).sort((left, right) => left - right);
    const strs = a.filter((e, i) => !type[i]).sort((left, right) => left.localeCompare(right));
    let nindex = 0, sindex = 0;
    return type.map(t => t ? nums[nindex++] : strs[sindex++]);
}
```

```js
console.log(sort(['5', '4', 'dog', '1', 'cat']));
// => ['1', '4', 'cat', '5', 'dog']

console.log(sort(['dog', 'cat']));
// => ['cat', 'dog']

console.log(sort(['5', '3']));
// => ['3', '5']

console.log(sort(['5', 'gazelle', '300']));
// => ['5', 'gazelle', '300']

function sort(a) {
    const type = a.map(e => /^\d+$/.test(e));
    const nums = a.filter((e, i) => type[i]).sort((left, right) => left - right);
    const strs = a.filter((e, i) => !type[i]).sort((left, right) => left.localeCompare(right));
    let nindex = 0, sindex = 0;
    return type.map(t => t ? nums[nindex++] : strs[sindex++]);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Or with ES5 and earlier syntax:

```js
console.log(sort(['5', '4', 'dog', '1', 'cat']));
// => ['1', '4', 'cat', '5', 'dog']

console.log(sort(['dog', 'cat']));
// => ['cat', 'dog']

console.log(sort(['5', '3']));
// => ['3', '5']

console.log(sort(['5', 'gazelle', '300']));
// => ['5', 'gazelle', '300']

function sort(a) {
    var type = a.map(function(e) { return /^\d+$/.test(e); });
    var nums = a.filter(function(e, i) { return type[i]; }).sort(function(left, right) {
        return left - right;
    });
    var strs = a.filter(function(e, i) { return !type[i]; }).sort(function(left, right) {
        return left.localeCompare(right);
    });
    var nindex = 0, sindex = 0;
    return type.map(function(t) {
        return t ? nums[nindex++] : strs[sindex++];
    });
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

...but I'd've asked them a bunch of questions about the data, as I might go another way if there were hundreds of thousands of entries.

Also note ensuring a numeric comparison for the numbers, and a correct lexicographic comparison for the strings (within the browser's feature set, anyway).

---

Side note: In my version, I detected numbers like this: `/^\d+$/.test(e)`. That only allows for **integers**, and doesn't allow for scientific notation. The alternative would be a variation on what adeneo did: `e !== "" && !isNaN(e)`, which coerces `e` to a number if it's not blank and checks if the result was `NaN` (which would mean it couldn't be converted). The check for `""` is because sadly, coercing `""` to number gives you `0` and so just `isNaN(e)` would give an incorrect result for `""`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit quick and not super efficient, but it's one potential solution that produces your output:

```
var sorter = function(array){
  let chars = [];
  let nums = [];

  array.forEach( (v,i) => {
    if(isNaN(+v)){
        chars.push(i);
    }
    else{
        nums.push(i);
    }
  });

  let newArray = [];

  let sortedChars = array.filter(a => isNaN(+a)).sort();
  let sortedNums = array.filter(a => !isNaN(+a)).sort();

  chars.forEach((value, index) => {
    newArray[value] = sortedChars[index];
  });

   nums.forEach((value, index) => {
    newArray[value] = sortedNums[index];
  });

  return newArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be easily done in many ways so you get your sorted array as

```
[1,4,5,'cat','dog']
```

So before sorting take another array of same size and make a mark

```
0 - means integer
1 - means string
```

So this new array would look like this

```
temp = [0, 0, 1, 0, 1];
```

Now after you have sorted just iterate over this and replace the 0 with incoming integers in order and 1 with strings

And you will get the required output.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an object for the typed values and sort accordingly. Then use the original array again and map the values ot the same type for the result set.

```js
function sort(array) {
    var order = {
            number: function (a, b) { return a - b; },
            string: function (a, b) { return a.localeCompare(b); },
            default: function () { return 0; },
        };
        temp = {};

    array.forEach(function (a) { (temp[typeof a] = temp[typeof a] || []).push(a); });
    Object.keys(temp).forEach(function (t) { temp[t].sort(order[t] || order.default); });
    return array.map(function (a) { return temp[typeof a].shift(); });
};

console.log(sort([5, 4, 'dog', 1, 'cat']));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```